# How does one refer to the amino acids in a peptide?

Tags: biochemistry

Once a part of a peptide an amino acid is no longer an amino acid, so how do we refer to the part of the peptide that was once amino acid x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of the peptide that was previously an amino acid molecule when free can be correctly referred to as an amino acid *residue* when bound in the peptide.

[A source](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-amino-acid-residue.html)